# Can I move my duplicate check to the repository in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have code in my service layer to check for duplicate titles:

```
   protected bool ValidateAccount(Account account)
    {
        var accounts = _accountRepository.GetPk(account.PartitionKey);
        if (accounts.Any(b => b.Title.Equals(account.Title) &&
                              !b.RowKey.Equals(account.RowKey)))
            _validationDictionary.AddError("", "Duplicate title");
        return _validationDictionary.IsValid;
    }
```

Can someone explain if I can move this code to my repository. Currently I have that looking like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Title required")]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant view model instead of repository (since you included the code for your Account view model), yes it is an option to move the code from the service layer since the validation is concerned only with Accounts. But, this means that some business logic will be in the view model while others will be in the service layer.

Typically, I prefer to keep all the business logic together in the service layer. I would leave the code as is.

On the other hand, if you actually did mean repository, then no that wouldn't be good either for the same reason (mixing business logic in service layer and data access layer).